# How to import multiple svgs in vue.js via vue-svg-loader

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, import, vue-component

I want to import multiple svg's in one vue component. The documentation says I Have to import each one of them, but how can I import multiple svgs in a much shorter and cleaner way?

vue-svg-loader documentation: https://vue-svg-loader.js.org/

```
<script>
import Info from "@/assets/svgs/info.svg";
import Help from "@/assets/svgs/help.svg";
import Close from "@/assets/svgs/close.svg";
// etc. pp.

export default {
  components: {
    Info,
    Help,
    Close
  }
</script>
```

What happens if I got over one hundred svg's I want to import?

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Could you embed them inside one giant XML file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a [base component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Base-component-names-strongly-recommended) and register it globally since you'll use it very frequently.

---

Create a `<BaseIcon>` component that uses [`require` with expression](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression) to create a context for the SVG modules:

```
<template>
  <Component
     :is="require(`@/assets/svgs/${name}.svg`).default"
     class="BaseIcon"
     v-bind="$attrs"
     @v-on="$listeners"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'BaseIcon',

  // Transparent wrapper component
  // https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Disabling-Attribute-Inheritance
  inheritAttrs: false,
  
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style>
 .BaseIcon {
   /* Add some default CSS declaration blocks */
 }
 </style>
```

**Note**: We use `<Component>` to handle [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components), which assumes you'll use `vue-svg-loader` and the SVGs are treated as components. If that is not the case, use an `<img>` tag instead and use `src` instead of `is`.

---

Registering the base component globally:

If you're only creating a single base component, you can just go to your `main.js` file and before mounting the app do:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import BaseIcon from './components/_base/BaseIcon.vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.component('BaseIcon', BaseIcon)

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Else, if you want something a little bit more complex, take a look at how [this boilerplate registers base components automatically](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/vue-enterprise-boilerplate/blob/master/src/components/_globals.js).

---

Finally, use the component like so:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <BaseIcon
      name="info"
    />
    <BaseIcon
      name="help"
    />
    <BaseIcon
      name="close"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SomeComp',
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Ricky, thank you very much - looks very accurat. 

I created the BaseIcon component, added it globaly in main.js and implemented via <BaseIcon name="search" />. 

But I got an error: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

Any idea?

Comment: fixed it with: `:is="require(`@/assets/svgs/${name}.svg`).default"`

Comment: @wittgenstein Chris explains why you need to use `default` depending on how the module is imported [here](https://youtu.be/7lpemgMhi0k?t=568).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the method described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59149533/2227743) did not work for me (Vue-CLI 3 + Vue 2).

Examples:
External SVG:

```
    <img :src="require(`@/assets/img/icons/base/config.svg`).default" />
```

Inline SVG (dynamic component):

```
    <component :is="require(`@/assets/img/icons/base/config.svg?inline`)" />
```

Inline SVG (component):

```
<template><config-icon /></template>
import ConfigIcon from '@/components/icons/config-icon.vue';
```

Add the code below to **vue.config.js**:

```
      chainWebpack: (config) => {
       const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg');

       svgRule.uses.clear();
       svgRule.delete('type');
       svgRule.delete('generator');

       svgRule
        .oneOf('inline')
        .resourceQuery(/inline/)
        .use('babel-loader')
        .loader('babel-loader')
        .end()
        .use('vue-svg-loader')
        .loader('vue-svg-loader')
        .end()
        .end()
        .oneOf('external')
        .use('file-loader')
        .loader('file-loader')
        .options({
          name: 'assets/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
        });
      },
```