# Looking for guidance on building an icon picker for a VueJS app. How to load and display all Svgs from a folder inside a VueJS component?

Tags: vue.js, svg, vue-component

I am trying to make my own icon picker (similar to the fontawesome Icon Picker)in a Vuejs project and I was wondering if there was a way to load all of the svgs I have in my specific svgs folder to then display them on a page.

Is there a best way of going about this?
In VueJS,I can't import a folder full of svgs I believe, so how can you load all imgs/svgs from a single folder.

Should I load all svgs into a separate component and import that component somewhere else?

I'm not looking for someone to do this for me, but I am relatively new to coding and am not sure where to start with this implimentation and could really use some guidance!

Cheers!

This is a snapshot of what I am looking to build (obviously with all different svgs):

[image]

The list of svgs also look some thing like this:

[image]

Comment: Hello, I had almost the same problem that you have. See this thread about the [vue-svg-loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59148672/how-to-import-multiple-svgs-in-vue-js-via-vue-svg-loader). But maybe if you want to build an icon picker with thousands of svgs, maybe you need a script to generate the components automatically, or something like that.

Comment: Thank your for the response and I will definitely check this out!