# How can I dynamically load svg icons from node_modules folder in my nuxt js component?

Tags: vue.js, svg, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I am trying to use this library [cryptocurrency-icons](https://github.com/spothq/cryptocurrency-icons) from Github inside my Nuxt SSR project

This library adds all the svg icons to ./node_modules/cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color directory

I made the following component in the components/BaseCryptoIcon.vue file

```
<template>
  <Component
    :is="
      require(`~/node_modules/cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color/${name}.svg`)
        .default
    "
    class="BaseIcon"
    v-bind="$attrs"
    @v-on="$listeners"
  />
</template>

<script>
/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59148672/how-to-import-multiple-svgs-in-vue-js-via-vue-svg-loader
 */
export default {
  name: 'BaseIcon',

  // Transparent wrapper component
  // https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Disabling-Attribute-Inheritance
  inheritAttrs: false,

  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style>
.BaseIcon {
  /* Add some default CSS declaration blocks */
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
</style>
```

When I try to use it in my pages/Index.vue file as following nothing is rendered. It is not giving any error either

```
<template lang="pug">
  base-crypto-icon(name='btc')
</template>

<script lang="javascript">
import BaseCryptoIcon from '~/components/BaseCryptoIcon.vue'
export default {
  components: {BaseCryptoIcon}
}
</script>
```

Can someone kindly tell me how I can make this work in Vue/Nuxt

Comment: Are you checking for errors on both (browser and server) sides? And what is the behavior? The component doesn't get rendered or does it break somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to make method in components/BaseCryptoIcon.vue:

```
getIcon(name)  {
  return require(`~/node_modules/cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color/${name}.svg`).default
}
```

then in template:

```
 <Component
    :is="getIcon(name)"
  />
```

Probably related question from 2 days ago:
[Why image path is not resolved by require() when passed as prop in NuxtJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68652147/why-image-path-is-not-resolved-by-require-when-passed-as-prop-in-nuxtjs)

Comment: :( no luck it wont render

Comment: It's very likely your problem is in require. Specially if you are making a require().default inside the prop. It's a good practice to leave all complex operations on the script area, outside the template.

Comment: this works perfectly all that was needed to be done was add @nuxtjs/svg module to the nuxt config file! thank you Andre you saved my day

Comment: Yay! (I mean Yarrr!) I'm so glad to help your life, Pirate person! :)