# Provide fallback for dynamically required icon that was loaded with @nuxtjs/svg in nuxt 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Nuxt 2 component

```
<template>
  <div
    class="crypto__icon"
    v-html="
      require(`~/node_modules/cryptocurrency-icons/svg/color/${name}.svg?raw`)
    "
  ></div>
</template>

<script>
/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59148672/how-to-import-multiple-svgs-in-vue-js-via-vue-svg-loader
 */
export default {
  name: "BaseIcon",

  // Transparent wrapper component
  // https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Disabling-Attribute-Inheritance
  inheritAttrs: false,

  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.crypto__icon {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
}
</style>
```

- I am requiring an svg in my nuxt 2 application
- If the icon with given name does not exist I want to "require('~..../color/generic.svg?raw')" else load the icon with the given name
- Here is the [full codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cryptocurrency-icons-npm-working-jr4pc?file=/components/BaseIcon.vue)

Currently it gives me an error if the icon is not found
[image]

How do I dynamically determine if the icon exists, render if it does and return a fallback if it doesnt without making the entire application crash

Comment: Make `v-html` as a computed value? Like `try {const svg = require(...); return svg?svg:defaultSvg}catch(e){return defaultSvg}`